# How to place certain files in the root directory of the Grails server?

Tags: apache-flex, grails, configuration

I am using a grails application as backend for a Flex frontend. To be able to easily develop and debug my applications I would need to place a crossdomain.xml file into the root of the server, i.e. it must be accessible via http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml. Similar use cases might be the deployment of a favicon.ico or a robots.txt, however this can be done in the production environment through a tomcat server with a default root web application.

In my case however I need to have the crossdomain.xml available after running grails run-app. I know that I can move the entire application to the root (http://ca.rroll.net/2009/03/27/configuring-the-grails-root-application-context/) however this is also not what I want, since the grails application should still reside below its default application context.

Does somebody know, how I can do this? Will I have to reconfigure the jetty servlet container of my grails installation somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. I haven't tried this yet, so YMMV.

In this [article](http://colinharrington.net/blog/2008/07/grails-jetty-and-crossdomainxml/), Colin Harrington discusses making a crossdomain.xml file available at the root of the server by deploying an additional Jetty context.

His technique was first proposed in this blog [entry](http://www.jtict.com/blog/grails-jetty-multiple-contexts/), where the author also discusses using the [Static Resources Plugin](http://grails.org/Static+Resources+Plugin) as another alternative

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to solve this with Apache and mod_proxy.  This allows both your Grails install and Grails project to remain pristine.  No hacking at the Grails internals, no adding plug-ins you may not need in production.

**1. Install Apache httpd 2.2**

Do this however makes the most sense for your operating system.  It is important that you install Apache 2.2.  I did this on an Ubuntu system, so any specific commands and file locations will be for Ubuntu.  Modify as necessary for your system.

After you've installed Apache, start httpd.

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd start
```

Test that it is installed correctly using a web browser.

**2. Create a root directory**

Pick a location on your disk where you will keep your static files.  This will be the document root for httpd.  I will be using /var/grails_root.

```
mkdir /var/grails_root
touch /var/grails_root/crossdomain.xml
```

**3. Create a VirtualHost in httpd.conf**

Open httpd.conf in your favorite text editor.

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Pick your favorite port, and create a virtual host on that port.  I will be using 9090, but any port will do.

Add these lines to httpd.conf

```
Listen 9090
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot "/var/grails_root"
    <Directory "/var/grails_root">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart httpd

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```

Test that you are now able to access the static files in your document root directory.  If not, you will need to fix this before moving on to the next step.

**4. Enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http**

You need to load both of these modules.  mod_proxy has the base functionality for proxying, and the mod_proxy_xxx modules have information specific to a protocol.  They ship standard with httpd 2.2, so you shouldn't need to install anything extra.

Add these lines to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Now modify the virtual host you set up in the previous step.  (You can omit the comments)

```
<VirtualHost *:9090>
    DocumentRoot "/var/grails_root"
    <Directory "/var/grails_root">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
# New lines start here
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /grailsApp http://your.grails.server:8080/grailsApp
# New lines end here
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart httpd

```
sudo /sbin/service httpd restart
```

Now, you should be able to access both your static files and your Grails app via port 9090.

This is all based on information found here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Configuring+mod_proxy

Information for doing this with other versions of Apache is available on the same site.

Comment: Long is not an issue.  Unless your blog's going to be around for all eternity (highly unlikely), paraphrase (or, hell, just copy) the content here.  Answers should be more than just "go here to see the answer".

Comment: Okay.  Replaced the link with relevant text from the blog post.