# grails run-app serve files from root context

Tags: tomcat, grails

How does one serve up files from the root context when running a grails application with run-app. For example, I want to serve up robots.txt file from `/robots.txt` and serve up my application from `/mygrailsapp/`.

Does grails run-app use tomcat? How do you configure the tomcat plugin to serve static files from the root context?

Failed paths taken thus far...

1) I found a way to set the project to the root context so everything is served from the root context but this is not want I want. http://nickcarroll.me/2009/03/27/configuring-the-grails-root-application-context/

2) I found an old post (2008) describing how to enable multiple contexts with run-app and jetty. Does run-app still use jetty?
http://colinharrington.net/blog/2008/07/grails-jetty-and-crossdomainxml/

Similar to question [How to place certain files in the root directory of the Grails server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836722/how-to-place-certain-files-in-the-root-directory-of-the-grails-server) but I want a solution that is contained within the grails project.

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: Are you just trying to show robots.txt from /mygrailsapp/robots.txt or is it important that the actual file live in the first level directory on the file system?

Comment: in order for web crawlers to detect robots.txt, it must be served from / and will not be recognized from /mygrailsapp/ Where it lives on the file system does not matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging it looks like this is easy.

First, embedded tomcat can be configured via scripts/_Events.groovy with the eventConfigureTomcat event handler. http://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/grails-tip-configuring-embedded-tomcat-instance-used-in-developmenttest-env/

Second, you can add another context to serve out files from root. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Add-virtual-directory-in-grails-tomcat-plugin-td2234448.html#a2234448

```
import org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader

eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    File dir = new File("./scripts/rootContext")
    def rootContext = tomcat.addWebapp("/", dir.getAbsolutePath())
    rootContext.reloadable = true
    rootContext.loader = new WebappLoader(tomcat.class.classLoader)

    //bonus answer - gzip json response
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute("compression", "on")
    tomcat.connector.setAttribute("compressableMimeType", "applicatio/json")
}
```

start grails with run-app and `/robots.txt` will get served from scripts/rootContext/robots.txt.